# Design pattern with async with nested classes in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an issue in a personal project. I have developed a class to encapsulate an Http client which use `aiohttp` so it uses async code.

I have several classes (related to different REST services) that use this client by composition.
In every method of the service classes, I call the http client.
The code of the Http client looks like (I have simplified for the example):

```
class HttpClientSession:
    """
    This class is used to interfacing Http server.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        http_url: str,
        auth: Optional[BasicAuth] = None,
    ):
        """
        Constructs the Http client.

        :param http_url: URL to connect to Http server.
        :param auth: Authentication to connect to server.
        :raises Exception: If URL is empty.
        """
        logger.debug("Create Http client")

        if not http_url:
            raise Exception("Http URL is invalid")
        self._url: str = http_url

        #: Server authentication
        self._auth: Optional[BasicAuth] = auth

        #: HTTP session
        self._session: Optional[ClientSession] = None

        logger.debug("Http client created")

    async def __aenter__(self):
        """
        Create Http session to send requests.
        """
        self._session = ClientSession(
            auth=self._auth,
            raise_for_status=True,
            connector=TCPConnector(limit=50),
        )
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *err):
        """
        Close Http session.
        """
        await self._session.close()
        self._session = None

    async def get(self, suffix_url: str, headers: dict, query: Any = None):
        """
        Send a GET request.

        :param suffix_url: Last part of the URL contains the request.
        :param headers: Header for the request.
        :param query: Query of the request.
        :return: Response.
        """
        async with self._session.get(
            url=self._url + suffix_url,
            headers=headers,
            params=query,
        ) as response:
            return await response.json()

class HttpClient:
    """
    This class is used to interfacing Http server.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        http_url: str,
        auth: Optional[BasicAuth] = None,
    ):
        """
        Constructs the Http client.

        :param http_url: URL to connect to Http server.
        :param auth: Authentication to connect to server.
        :raises Exception: If URL is empty.
        """
        logger.debug("Create Http client")

        #: HTTP session
        self._session: HttpClientSession = HttpClientSession(http_url, auth)

        logger.debug("Http client created")

    async def get(self, suffix_url: str, headers: dict, query: Any = None):
        """
        Send a GET request.

        :param suffix_url: Last part of the URL contains the request.
        :param headers: Header for the request.
        :param query: Query of the request.
        :return: Response.
        """
        async with self._session as session:
            return await session.get(suffix_url,headers, query)
```

To be more efficient, I would like to be able to reuse an Http Session that's why I have created a session class which permit me to use the async with syntax by the caller but if it is not needed, the caller can call directly the `HttpClient` method which create a dedicate session.

So it is convenient because I can write:

```
http_client = HttpClient(...)
http_client.get(...)
```

or

```
http_client = HttpClient(...)
async with http_client as http_session:
    http_session.get(...)
    http_session.get(...)
```

So great it works but now my issue is I would like to do the same for user of services classes to be also able to reuse session or not. I'm a bit stuck but my intention is to have this syntax also :

```
client = ServiceClient(...)
client.do_something(...)  # do_something will call http_client.get(...)
```

or

```
client = ServiceClient(...)
async with client as session:
    session.do_something(...) # do_something will call http_session.get(...)
    session.do_something_else(...)  # do_something_else will reuse http_session
```

but I don't want to do every time:

```
client = ServiceClient(...)
async with client as session:
    session.do_something(...) # session is not reuse so I don't want boilerplate of async with
```

I have tried to define `__aenter__` method but I haven't found an elegant way to avoid duplication of code.

Have you some ideas ?

I have tried to add the same pattern used in `HttpClient` and `HttpClientSession` classes in services classes but haven't succeed to have `ServiceClient` call `HttpClient` and `ServiceClientSession` call `HttpClientSession`.

And in fact I'm even not sure it is the better pattern to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution.

For the `HttpClient` I have refactor to remove the `HttpClientSession` class and manage optional session:

```
class HttpClient:
    """
    This class is used to interfacing Http server.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        http_url: str,
        auth: Optional[BasicAuth] = None,
    ):
        """
        Constructs the Http client.

        :param http_url: URL to connect to Http server.
        :param auth: Authentication to connect to server.
        :raises Exception: If URL is empty.
        """
        logger.debug("Create Http client")

        if not http_url:
            raise Exception("Http URL is invalid")
        self._url: str = http_url

        #: Server authentication
        self._auth: Optional[BasicAuth] = auth

        #: HTTP session
        self._session: Optional[ClientSession] = None

        logger.debug("Http client created")

    async def __aenter__(self):
        """
        Create Http session to send requests.
        """
        self._session = ClientSession(
            auth=self._auth,
            raise_for_status=True,
            connector=TCPConnector(limit=50),
        )
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *err):
        """
        Close Http session.
        """
        await self._session.close()
        self._session = None

    async def get(self, suffix_url: str, headers: dict, query: Any = None):
        """
        Send a GET request.

        :param suffix_url: Last part of the URL contains the request.
        :param headers: Header for the request.
        :param query: Query of the request.
        :return: Response.
        """
        if self._session:
            async with self._session.get(
                    url=self._url + suffix_url,
                    headers=headers,
                    params=query,
            ) as response:
                return await response.json()
        else:
            async with ClientSession(
                auth=self._auth,
                raise_for_status=True,
                connector=TCPConnector(limit=50),
            ) as session:
                async with session.get(
                    url=self._url + suffix_url,
                    headers=headers,
                    params=query,
                ) as response:
                    return await response.json()
```

And in service class, I have defined also the methods to support async with syntax:

```
    async def __aenter__(self):
        """
        Create session to send requests.
        """
        await self._http_client.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *err):
        """
        Close session.
        """
        await self._http_client.__aexit__(*err)
```

So it works but I don't know if there is a better way to do it because I'm not fan of the if-else statement.